# Azure Trigger Function Integration Test With Wiremock

Tags: java, azure-functions, integration-testing, wiremock

I have an Azure TimerTrigger running (fully functional) with spring boot and am running into an issue running an integration test. Below is what my function looks like.

When I use `mvn azure-functions:run` I am able to hit http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/myTrigger as defined in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http)

```
@FunctionName("myTrigger")
public void execute(
    @TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "%myCronSetting%") String timerInfo,
    final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        handleRequest(timerInfo, context);
    }
```

However, I always get 404 responses when running my integration test using wiremock

```
when().post("/admin/functions/myTrigger").then().log().body().statusCode(202);
```

I suspect the function itself isn't starting up with spring when running the integration test but that's just a guess. I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I have seen other related answers with C# where they have code to trigger the function inside their test but I cannot find a way to do that in java (nor do I know it that's even possible)

Comment: Not clear on why you are using wiremock here. For integration testing, you would want to simple run the function app and then use JUnit tests to make HTTP requests as required and assert the output.

Comment: I have done both. I am trying to get the integration test automated though.